Percona pt-query-digest vs. Performance Insights on AWS Aurora 3.x
Several years ago when I was running MySQL on-prem and then EC2, I found Percona pt-query-digest to be very useful to find poorly performing SQL in prod. It's been a while since I've used it. AWS Performance Insights has similar functionality. Other than the fact that it's free, are there any advantages to pt-query-digest over PI?

Could you supply an example of PI; I don't have access at the moment.  I do like pt-query-digest for summarizing the slowlog.
